# Command Output being read differently by distinct PowerShell commands

Tags: powershell, variables, replace, diff

I am developing a PowerShell script that will make use of the `Get-ClusterNode` cmdlet in a fileserver cluster, in order to monitor whether the right resources are in their primary locations or not.

The thing is, in order to verify this, I inserted some where conditions and some .search/.replace lines, being thrown into a variable.

When I `Write-Host` the variable `$X` content it shows me this:

`BR10 BR20 BR30 BR40`

Each of these are resources from a Microsoft Failover Cluster Group.

Then I copied this result and threw it into another variable (`$Y`) to be used as a matrix for the diff check.

Then I did this:

```
$result = if (diff $X $Y) {
    'Problem'
} else {
    'OK'
}
Write-Host $result
```

It always tells me "Problem". I double checked the variables and they are identical.

Then I tried it in another way:

```
Compare-Object $X $Y
```

The result was this:

```
PS C:\SplunkForwarder\bin\scripts> C:\SplunkForwarder\bin\scripts\Get-ClusterInfo.ps1

InputObject                                                 SideIndicator  
----------                                                  -----------  
BR10 BR20 BR30 BR40                                              =>
BR10                                                             <=
BR20                                                             <=
BR30                                                             <=
BR40                                                             <=
```

Why would that happen? The variables are identical when I print them on the screen!

I then tested this:

```
$Search = " `n"
$Replace = ""

$X = ($X.Replace($Search, $Replace))
```

But even when the replacement job results in success, the behavior is the same when comparing both variables.

Comment: how did you do the copy from $X to $Y? It looks like one is a string and the other is a tuple

Comment: Try to reveal how `$x` and `$y` are actual laid out using `ConvertTo-JSON`

Comment: Please show the code you're using to populate `$X` and `$Y`.

Comment: Use `Compare-Object ($x -join ' ') ($y -join ' ')` as @GarrGodfrey is right. Check `$x.GetType()` and `$y.GetType()` and `Write-Output $X` instead of `Write-Host $X`. Read [`Write-Host` considered harmful](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. @JosefZ, The result of the GetType is this:

https://ibb.co/iTw7Cw

Though, the output of the suggested Compare-Object with the -join thingy is blank.

Comment: @JosefZ's answer actually helped me to solve part of this deal with this line:

$X = -join $X

Thank you! :)